# Использование пустых интерфейсов для объединения типов объектов

Tags: php, ооп

Я набросал схематический класс `Logger`, и два класса, `ReadException` и `WriteException`, которые расширяют класс `Exception`. В клиентском коде соответственно есть блок для отлавливания исключений. В этом варианте получается так, что если я добавлю ещё один класс (например `FooException`), то и в блоке `try {} catch () {}` мне понадобится дописать ещё один блок `catch (FooException $e) {}`. Вот псевдокод:

```
class ReadException extends Exception
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('Ошибка чтения файла!');
    }
}

class WriteException extends Exception
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('Ошибка записи в файл!');
    }
}

class Logger
{
    /**
     * @return Logger
     * @throws ReadException
     */
    public function readLines(): Logger
    {
        if (true) { // false|true для переключения срабатывания исключений
            throw new ReadException();
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @throws WriteException
     */
    public function writeLines(): void
    {
        if (false) { // false|true для переключения срабатывания исключений
            throw new WriteException();
        }
    }
}


try {
    $logger = new Logger();
    $logger->readLines()->writeLines();
} catch (ReadException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
} catch (WriteException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
} // и тут может быть сколько угодно блоков catch(){}
```

Я додумался использовать пустой интерфейс Exceptions, и это позволило записать всего один блок catch:

```
try {
    $logger = new Logger();
    $logger->readLines()->writeLines();
} catch (Exceptions $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Вот вариант с интерфейсом:

```
interface Exceptions {}

class ReadException extends Exception implements Exceptions
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('Ошибка чтения файла!');
    }
}

class WriteException extends Exception implements Exceptions
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('Ошибка записи в файл!');
    }
}

class Logger
{
    /**
     * @return Logger
     * @throws ReadException
     */
    public function readLines(): Logger
    {
        if (true) { // false|true для переключения срабатывания исключений
            throw new ReadException();
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @throws WriteException
     */
    public function writeLines(): void
    {
        if (false) { // false|true для переключения срабатывания исключений
            throw new WriteException();
        }
    }
}

try {
    $logger = new Logger();
    $logger->readLines()->writeLines();
} catch (Exceptions $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Вариант с интерфейсом позволяет создавать сколько угодно классов, расширяющих Exception, и при этом не нужно в клиентском коде ничего дописывать.

Суть вопроса: можно ли использовать пустые интерфейсы только лишь для объединения типов объектов? Это нормальная практика?

Comment: По сути, можно так делать, никто не запрещает. Когда-то в zf тоже видел пустые интерфейсы, которые, в основном, делались с заделом на будущее (но это не точно).

Comment: Для этого вообще-то есть базовый Throwable, который уже интерфейс. Если у вас функциональность не отличается от него, зачем плодить другие интерфейсы?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov вынесите, пожалуйста, ваш комментарий в ответ. Спасибо!

Comment: а зачем делить на интерфейсы `ReadException`, `WriteException`, если обработка у них будет одинаковая? А если будет разная, то в любом случае надо будет где-то проверять какое из исключений пришло, и почему бы не делать это именно в catch?

Comment: @Grundy ну а как ещё сделать правильно обработку исключений? Вроде же логично - под каждую ошибку отдельный класс с общим интерфейсом. А общий интерфейс как раз позволяет не вмешиваться в клиентский код после добавления нового класса. Или вы считаете иначе?

Comment: @Эдуард,а ты полностью мой комментарий прочитал?

Comment: @Grundy из вашего камента становится понятно, что вы бы сделали иначе. Вопрос - как?

Comment: @Эдуард, в моем комментарии два вопроса, можешь на них ответить?

Comment: @Grundy `1.` _а зачем делить на интерфейсы ReadException, WriteException, если обработка у них будет одинаковая?_ - ответ: _Вроде же логично - под каждую ошибку отдельный класс с общим интерфейсом. А общий интерфейс как раз позволяет не вмешиваться в клиентский код после добавления нового класса._ `2.` _А если будет разная, то в любом случае надо будет где-то проверять какое из исключений пришло, и почему бы не делать это именно в catch?_  - ответ: _Ну хотя бы потому, что бы не плодить одинаковые блоки кода._

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101434/discussion-between-grundy-and-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В PHP есть базовый интерфейс [Throwable](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.throwable.php), который может использован как основа, если он не отличается по функциональности от вашего.

Answer (score 0):

Используй по мере необходимости. Приведу абстрактный пример:

```
// В этом примере пустые интерфейсы будут служить в качестве чего-то, похожего 
// на "атрибут без значения" или же "свойство", наличие которого указывает
// на владение технологией PHP или Javascript (конкретно для этого примера).

// создаем 2 интерфейса (после того как внимательно прочитали коментарий выше)
interface Php {}
interface Javascript {}

// создаем абстрактный клас разработчиков и добавляем метод для получения резюме
abstract class Developer 
{
    protected $resume = '';
    public function getResume(): string
    {
        return $this->resume.PHP_EOL;
    }
}

// бекенд разработчик реализовывает интерфейс Php, что означает владение технологией PHP.
class BackendDeveloper extends Developer implements Php
{
    protected $resume = 'I am Backend developer PHP';
}

// фронтенд разработчик реализовывает интерфейс Javascript, что означает владение технологией Javascript.
class FrontendDeveloper extends Developer implements Javascript
{
    protected $resume = 'I am Frontend developer JAVASCRIPT';
}

// фулстак разработчик реализовывает интерфейсы Php и Javascript, что означает владение этими технологиями.
class FullstackDeveloper extends Developer implements Php, Javascript
{
    protected $resume = 'I am Fullstack developer PHP and JAVASCRIPT';
}

// начинающий разработчик не реализовывает интерфейсы Php или Javascript, он не владеет технологиями.
class JuniorDeveloper extends Developer
{
    protected $resume = 'I am junior developer i know nothink';
}

// создаем класс вакансий компании для разработчиков
class CompanyVacancies
{
    // "вакансия: инженер PHP", и для того чтоб на вакансию попадали разработчики владеющие PHP,
    // указываем для ожидаемого параметра тип нашего пустого интерфейса Php
    public function engineerPhp(Php $developer): void
    {
        echo 'PHP Engineer: '.$developer->getResume();
    }
    
    // "вакансия: инженер Javascript", аналогично, мы ожидаем разработчиков владеющии Javascript,
    // указываем для ожидаемого параметра тип нашего пустого интерфейса Javascript
    public function engineerJavascript(Javascript $developer): void
    {
        echo 'Javascript Engineer: '.$developer->getResume();
    }
    
    // "вакансия: начинающий разработчик", на эту вакансию не требуется Php или Javascript,
    // указываем для ожидаемого параметра тип Developer.
    public function juniorDeveloper(Developer $developer): void
    {
        echo 'Junior Developer: '.$developer->getResume();
    }
}

// генерируем по разработчику каждой специализации
$backend = new BackendDeveloper();
$frontend = new FrontendDeveloper();
$fullstack = new FullstackDeveloper();
$junior = new JuniorDeveloper();

// генерируем вакансии компании
$companyVacancies = new CompanyVacancies();

// пробуем устраивать разработчиков на каждую вакансию

$companyVacancies->engineerPhp($backend); // отобразит резюме бекенд разработчика
//$companyVacancies->engineerPhp($frontend); // ошибка, фронтенд не владеет PHP
$companyVacancies->engineerPhp($fullstack); // отобразит резюме фулстак разработчика
//$companyVacancies->engineerPhp($junior); // ошибка, джун не владеет PHP

//$companyVacancies->engineerJavascript($backend); // ошибка, бекенд не владеет Javascript
$companyVacancies->engineerJavascript($frontend); // отобразит резюме фронтенд разработчика
$companyVacancies->engineerJavascript($fullstack); // отобразит резюме фулстак разработчика
//$companyVacancies->engineerJavascript($junior); // ошибка, джун не владеет Javascript

$companyVacancies->juniorDeveloper($backend); // отобразит резюме бекенд разработчика
$companyVacancies->juniorDeveloper($frontend); // отобразит резюме фронтенд разработчика
$companyVacancies->juniorDeveloper($fullstack); // отобразит резюме фулстак разработчика
$companyVacancies->juniorDeveloper($junior); // отобразит резюме джуна
```

Answer (score -2):

Не думаю что это правильно, потому что Интерфейсы как раз описывают ПОВЕДЕНИЕ, а если в интерфейсе ничего то и интерфейс не нужен. Представь себе клавиатуру без кнопок, кому и зачем она нужна?

Comment: Интерфейс являясь `Типом` сам по себе несет информацию, даже если он совершенно пустой